# How to use ADAL .Net library on-premise Single Page JS application

Tags: adfs, adal

I have a scenario where in I want to authorize my web api which is a part of different application.

Let say I have a Single Page application "A". Now "A" wants to call an api present in application "B" via ajax or angulars $http.

Now to do that, can I create a web api in application "A" which will return me the token for application "B" when called via ajax and save that token in browsers session storage.

Can i use this code in my application "A" web api to return me token

```
string authority = "https://adfs.corp.adfssample.com/adfs";
string resourceURI = "https://adfssample.com/OWIN-ADAL-ADFS-WebMVC";
string clientID = "82A2A9DE-131B-4837-8472-EDE0561A0EF6";
string clientReturnURI = "http://anarbitraryreturnuri/";
var ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, clientID, new Uri(clientReturnURI), new AuthorizationParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle));
string authHeader = ar.CreateAuthorizationHeader
```

And now every ajax call to Application "B" will have this token in header.